# Adding a line to a CSV file, without changing its format (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a python script that opens a logfile, writes specific information to a new csv file and then compares the time difference between each action within the log file. The problem I'm having is that I need to figure a way to add the time difference to the new csv file after it was closed during the first writing process. This is what I have so far for that part.

```
final_file = open('FinalLogFile.csv', 'w')
temp_logfile = csv.reader(open('tempLogFile.csv', 'rb'), delimiter="\t")

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
row_count = 0

#find the time between each action and write it to the new file
#transfer actions from temp file to final file
for row in temp_logfile:
    time = (row[0] + " " + row[1])
    timestamp = strptime(time, fmt)
    current_value = mktime(timestamp)

    row_count+=1
    if row_count == 1:
        previous_value = current_value

    #print ("%s - %s" %(current_value, previous_value))
    total_value = current_value - previous_value

    final_file.write('%s, %s' %(row,total_value) + '\n')

    previous_value = current_value
final_file.close()

#remove the temp logfile
rm_command = "rm ~/log_parsing/tempLogFile.csv"
os.system(rm_command)
```

Right now, it does add the time at the end of each row, however, the formatting is completely different from the original and it adds comma's between each letter, space, character and number. Is there way to keep the original format of the temp file or just add the time into the original temp file without creating a new one?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `row` returned by `csv.reader` is a list.
With `final_file.write('%s, %s' % (row,total_value) + '\n')` you're writing:

1. a list (whose repr is comma-delimited)
2. the time difference
3. a new line

But you can do all of that in one step using `csv.writer`:

```
final_file = csv.writer(open('FinalLogFile.csv', 'wb'), delimiter="\t")
...
    row.append(total_value)
    final_file.writerow(row)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just tried your suggestion and I got this error "_csv.Error: sequence expected"

Comment: @user1186173: My mistake. `.append()` returns `None` not the list itself. I've updated the example.

Comment: That definitely worked much better, but now it's not actually going to the next line.

Comment: I got it, i just did row.append("\n") after the first row.append and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1186173: That's interesting. You shouldn't need to manually append a line-feed. If you have time, please describe the behavior you're seeing in more detail.  Because adding another `\n` might make the file more difficult to read in for someone who doesn't know how it was created.

Comment: And make sure you're opening the output file with `wb`. On Windows this matters. The line-ending issue you're seeing might be a result of the way Windows handles line-endings.