# Reading and formatting CSV file (New Line Insertion)

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that has numerous data points included in each row, despite belonging to the same column. Something similar to this:

```
A, B, C, X, Y, Z
```

Now, what I would like to do is to reformat the file such that the resulting CSV is:

```
A, B, C
X, Y, Z
```

I'm not too sure how to go about this / express it in a pythonic way. One idea (which I wasn't sure how to code) was to create a for loop similar to

```
For elements in file:
   new_csv = []
   counter = 0
   max_counter = 3

   ##I'm using english because I dont know how to express it in python syntax
   take first element in CSV and add 1 to counter
   append first element to new_csv
   is counter < max_counter?
       if yes: go to next element
       if no: append /n to new csv then go to next element
```

This probably is a terrible way to do it, but I'm struggling to find another way. How would I express this in the python syntax? Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean you want to split the six elements into two three element lines?

Comment: right, then I want to write it to a new csv

Comment: OK then, can you format your CSV lines as code? right now the two lines are on the same line

Comment: Have a look at this post on stackoverflow [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777409/adding-a-line-to-a-csv-file-without-changing-its-format-python

Answer (score 3):

Just write two rows to an output [`csv.writer()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as infh, open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerows([row[:3], row[3:]])
```

Each row the `csv.reader()` object produces is a list object, so all we have to do is using the [Python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) to slice of a new list object of the first 3 elements, and another list object for the remaining 3 elements.

Comment: I am really unsure about the `"wb"` for writing csv. The documentation doesn't use this in the examples and I think you loose the encoding facility in this case. This supposes you manipulate bytes all the way (and only works because you read also with `rb`, or you get `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`)

Comment: @Cilyan: Python 2 recommends you use `rb` so that the CSV reader and writer objects fully control line endings. Python 3 uses `newline=''` instead, to the same purpose. So the recommendation differs between the Python versions here.

Comment: @Cilyan: Since Python 2 is still used by a majority of people, I stick to that; the `csv.writer` documentation link goes to the Python 2 documentation, you may note.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use python's [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as input_file, open("output.csv", "w+"):
    input_csv, output_csv = csv.reader(input_file), csv.writer(output_file);
    for row in input_csv:
        output_csv.writerows([row[:len(row)/2],row[len(row)/2]]);
```

Which given the input

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

will output

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
A,B,C
D,E,F,G
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: I think there are several typos here (missing target for the second open, missing colon.)

Answer (score 0):

*This solution is for Python 3. For Python 2, see [Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21784082/1970751) (differs in the way files are opened).*

Python has a module to [read](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.writer#csv.reader) and [write](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.writer#csv.writer) csv files. There are some [nice examples](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.writer#examples) in the official documentation on how to use them. (Note the `newline=""` for output file, this lets the csv module take care of line return, which according to the specification should be `\r\n`, `\n` being used for line feed in a cell.)

While reading, you then split the rows with [slicing](http://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-slice) and feed the parts in the writer.

```
import csv

# with ensures files are closed when leaving block
with open("in.csv", "r") as fin, open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=",")
    writer =csv.writer(fout, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    # Rows are each line of the csv returned as a list
    for row in reader:
        # Separate the row:
        # from beginning to 3rd element, and from 3rd element to end
        writer.writerows((row[:3], row[3:])
```